# Whose power reduction is better. Clock gating or Data enable?

Tags: power, vlsi

I am comparing **Clock Gating** (ECG) and **Data enable** methods in term of power reduction. Both can save power.

But which one is better?
I tried these 2 methods in a small design ( a d flipflop ) to a larger one (8-bit data register) and measured their power dissipation. The results always show that **Data enable** consumes less power than **Clock Gating.**

Then why is **Clock Gating** used so often for power reduction? Is there any cases when **Clock Gating** consumes more power than **Data enable** ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, when the clock is disabled to a large number of gates, there is power savings at each gate. Since the clock changes faster than data, the savings will be larger even if data changes every clock. Also, if the clock is stopped to a large number of gates, then all downstream logic will have static clock AND static data, because upstream registers are not getting clocked. So I think in a real example, clock gating will be more effective than data enable.

Comment: @mkeith That would make a good answer.

Comment: @mkeith so are there any cases when clock gating consumes more power than data enable. Cuz I once read a scientific newspaper on IEEE. The author implemented his proposed method in a simple pipeline ( no combinational parts among stages ) and compared it to Enable-based clock gating (ECG) and Data enable. It seemed that in some cases ECG consumed more power than Data enable. But I don't know when this will happen ? The experiment was assumed to assert enable signals on each stage all the time.

Comment: @Trunganhnguyễnthành Find that paper and post a link to it here. Chances are, your answer is detailed within it. Yes?

Comment: https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/SOCDC.2009.5423921

Comment: I don't think I have the expertise to answer this. That is why I commented with kind of a thought on the topic. However anyone who wants to use my words in an answer is welcome to do so with my blessing (no attribution required).

Comment: Here's my take from skimming that paper: The authors are suggesting a method to reduce power in a microprocessor. When an opcode is issued it is examined to determine which functional blocks will be needed at each stage of the pipeline. For any instruction this is done once and the choices are propagated through the instruction's stages. Each stage's functional units are then turned on or off based on what was decided at issue time. Thus complex heuristics can be evaluated once (when the instruction is issued) with the logic of decided what to power for each stage being simple yes/no choices.

Comment: The authors elaborate by saying that depending on the operation's data specific functional blocks can be disabled.  I take this to mean that e.g. for a MULTIPY instruction that has a 0 or 1 for one of its operands, the barrel shifter circuitry's clock could be disabled since it will never be needed.  IMO this technique is unlikely to show major power savings since it simply moves the decision-making circuitry from one part of the CPU to another.  (I could be wrong though since I only skimmed the paper.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on how much logic is shut down when you disable the clock, data or chip-select pins. Or when you throttle back the clock rate.

For a given design, one of these will have the most effect on power consumption. Due to the massive amount of logic in a CPU, it makes sense to throttle back power by disabling un-needed clocks. In so-called sleep modes, various clocks slow down and bus drivers may shut down. Unused devices will be shut down. For battery powered devices, every power management trick is used to save power.

Outside of a CPU, clocks tend to be point-of-use so little power is saved by disabling a clock. Instead, power is saved by disabling data flow using chip selects and gating the data itself or by slowing the data rate.

Slowing the clock rate also saves power and cuts down on heat, which saves power used for cooling. My Dell 690 workstation idles at 2.16 GHz but when busy, the CPU (8 cores) goes to 3.18 GHz briefly.

Today, most anything with a CPU or advanced MPU has various power saving modes, whether it runs on batteries or not. It is not a case of which power-saving option is better, but how many can be used at the same time, if the hardware allows it.